# Long Running Parallel ColdFusion Script Issues

Tags: coldfusion, parallel-processing

So here is my situation. I have a script which is hard-coded to always run two simultaneous threads (using cfthread). Basically the script takes an excel file or csv file and splits the data up into two sections and my script creates webpages in parallel.

However, it is apparent from the pages created that thread two (the threads are being spawned in a loop) completes its section of work... however thread one only gets a small portion of its work complete... the script also dies part way through. So I'm confused why this is happening? The only concern I have is that the actual function I run, createPage(...), is itself spawning a thread to do its work which is causing the server to freak out. I can't tell if this is happening for two reasons... One I do not have access to server monitoring at that level, and two, the createpage(...) function is black-boxed because it is a proprietary API function.

Any advice? Also, is there any way to have that createPage(...), if it is spawning a thread in its implementation, wait to complete before calling it again?

Here is psuedocode of how my code, in general is working:

```
<cfloop from=1 to=2>
<cfthread ...> //spawn threads
    <cfloop from="pageWorkStart" to="pageWorkFinish">
        <cfset createPage(...)> //at this point there are two threads calling this function, which itself may be spawning threads and is not waiting to finish... the server is potentially choking from queued processes backing up.
    </cfloop>
</cfthread>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: If the code is intended to create two webpages in parallel, which one does the user see?

Comment: Well it is just creating pages based off of a template I tell it to use. The pages themself have no main content, they are basically just initially created so they can be fleshed out with content with our CMS. Theoretically, the user would see them as soon as they have been created.

Comment: You could use FusionReactor or some other JVM monitoring tool to watch what's going on. However you're unlikely to be able to do this if "[you] do not have access to server monitoring at that level". You will need to get access. Or you might as well stop troubleshooting it. You can't have it both ways. Have you checked the log files to see if you're getting any errors or anything else relevant? Your (pseudo)code is not specific enough to really be commentworthy, I'm afraid.

Comment: Logs show an error everytime it fails (and it is erroring on the actual createPage function, eventually):

ReasonCode: 500
ReasonSubCode: 0
Message: Error in final (phase 2) validation - value fails Phase 1 validation
Suppressed: object of type 'class [Ljava.lang.Throwable;'

Comment: I also get: Closed the physical connection.

Comment: "...thread one only gets a small portion of its work complete... the script also dies part way through..."
Have you tried running that code separately outside of the thread to see what might be causing it to fail? Whenever I deal with cfthread, I often have to run the code on a test page outside of cfthread to see what's really going on.